# 2 Projects, 1 Solution. Project A calls forms from project B and vice versa. C# VS2010

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a project A that calls a form from project B. Form in project A gets disabled and Project B form opens. When closing I need project B to re-enable Project A form, but it does not allow me because I can't reference it due to circular reference. How do I go about referencing things in Project B from Project A?

Comment: Why dont you think of a Project C where your have reference to both project A & B?

Comment: The fact that these forms depend upon each other should inform you that they belong in the same project.

Comment: @ManojKumarRai I could do that, but I want a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Project B doesn't need a reference back to Project A. There are a number of ways you can achieve this:

a.) Project A's form opens the Project B form by calling `ShowDialog()` on it instead of `Show()`. This automatically disables A's form until B's is closed.

b.) Project A's form manually disables itself and starts listening to the `FormClosed` event on the Project B form. When the event fires, Project A's form enables itself again.

c.) In a special case where sometimes you need A's form to disable and show B's form, and sometimes you need B's form to disable and show A's form, you can do it by having Project A create both forms and pass one as a reference to the other. Add constructors to the forms that take another form as a reference:

```
private Form _formA;

public FormB(Form formA) {
    InitializeComponent();

    _formA = formA;
}

private void buttonFormA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    _formA.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: I ended up creating several namespaces for these two big projects, but what you are proposing would have done the trick in case I had stayed with the two project solution.